# Does libusb_bulk_transfer add CRC?

Tags: usb, interface, crc

0

I'm writing a user interface program for USB device in C++ using Visual Studio 2019. I'm using libusb library. I want to do bulk transfer to the device, and I'm trying to understand the exact function of libusb_bulk_transfer, more specifically - does it add CRC? The definition from the documentation:

```
 int libusb_bulk_transfer(struct libusb_device_handle *devh, unsigned char
 endpoint, unsigned char *data, int length, int *transferred, unsigned int
 timeout)

 Perform an USB bulk transfer.  A timeout value of zero means no
 timeout.
 The timeout value is given in milliseconds.
 Returns 0 on success,

 LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT if the transfer timed out,
 LIBUSB_ERROR_PIPE if the control request was not supported,
 LIBUSB_ERROR_OVERFLOW if the device offered more data,
 LIBUSB_ERROR_NO_DEVICE if the device has been disconnected and a
 LIBUSB_ERROR code on other failure.
```

From what I've understood, the function libusb_bulk_transfer creates the packet and transfers it to the desired endpoint for me, and I only need to supply it the data itself. when this function builds the packet, does it add a CRC?

If it doesn't, is there a different method to do the bulk transfer so I can control whether the CRC is added or not?

Comment: You don't need to calculate or add a CRC.  That's done for you.  I don't believe there is a way to toggle the CRC on/off via libusb.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just wanted to make sure that it's being sent since it's not mentioned in the definition of the function, and didn't know how to check it.

Comment: When I developed a USB driver using libusb I found the Total Phase Beagle protocol analyzer to be an indispensable tool.
https://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/ (low/full speed)
https://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb480/ (high speed).

Below is a question I posted and answered when I was developing a driver and ran into trouble.  You might be able to pull examples from it if you run into trouble.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605169/libusb-race-condition-using-asynchronous-i-o/49685399#49685399.  From the screenshots, the protocol analyzer displays the CRC.

Comment: Note, sometimes Total Phase runs sales and provides coupon codes.  I bought mine during a sale with a coupon code.  I'd suggest finding one and using it in order to same some money. Best of luck! :)